# New option asked about Multiple Application when generating a bundle since Symfony 2.8

Tags: symfony

Before Symfony 2.8 and because I was in need of a multiApp system in Symfony,

**I followed these two posts to achieve this :**

-http://jolicode.com/blog/multiple-applications-with-symfony2

-http://mihai-stancu.ro/2015/10/03/multiple-apps-in-one-repo-with-symfony2/

It's not really supported by SensioLabs but it works well, with a attached console option (`php app/console generate:bundle --app=app1` for example) to select on which app you need to use a command.

I see now since Symfony 2.8 that a new question is asked when generating a bundle :

> Welcome to the Symfony bundle generator!
>   Are you planning on sharing this bundle across multiple applications? [no]:

But I don't find anything about this feature nowhere across the net.
Is it related to a MultiApp functionality ? Any information about that ?

Thanks anyway & Best Regards !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

answer of [@michael-sivolobov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2261177/michael-sivolobov) is very Good.

But, I want to add more clarity in answering the Question:

> Are you planning on sharing this bundle across multiple applications?
>   [no]:

The Symfony Bundle generator needs to decide the useage of the generated bundle.

If this question is answered with `yes` : That means your generated Bundle will be Used "**as is**" with multiple projects, not Just for your current project, so you need to prefix a "**vendor**" name for your generated bundle, and also add the prefix to the namespace of the generated bundle.

Upon not following the convention, a message will print from the Console which reads:

> Each bundle is hosted under a namespace (like Acme/BlogBundle). The
>   namespace should begin with a "vendor" name like your company name,
>   your project name, or your client name, followed by one or more
>   optional category sub-namespaces, and it should end with the bundle
>   name itself (which must have Bundle as a suffix).
>
> See [Best Practice for Bundle Name](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html#bundle-name) for more details on bundle
>   naming conventions.
>
> Use / instead of \  for the namespace delimiter to avoid any problem.

File structure for the generated Bundle under `src/` dirctory will Be:

```
├─ src/
│  └─ yourVendor/
│     └─ yourBundle/
│        └─ Controller/ 
│        └─ DependencyInjection/
│        └─ Resources/
│        └─ Tests/
│        └─ yourVendorYourBundle.php/
```

If you answer this question with a `No` : This means you intend to use  your generated Bundle only for your Current Project, so you do not need the "**vendor**" name as the prefix as it is never going to be shared.

File structure for the generated Bundle under `src/` dirctory will Be:

```
├─ src/
│  └─ yourBundle/
│     └─ Controller/ 
│     └─ Resources/
│     └─ Tests/
│     └─ yourBundle.php/
```

Here is some good documentation on [Best Practices for creating projects](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html) .

Comment: Thanks for details !

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know how to answer use the default value.

This question is here because you can create bundle for sharing and you must name it with vendor name (like everyone did before [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/creating-the-project.html) had been posted).

But you also can create bundle for internal usage only as a main bundle of your application or some helpful bundle. And so you don't need vendor name in the name of your bundle. And answering `no` on this question generator will generate you not `YourVendorName/AppBundle` but simple `AppBundle`.

Also if answering `yes` configuration will be generated in `xml` format while answering `no` leads to `annotation` format.

So you don't need to worry about multiple apps if you generate them as separate bundles.

Comment: Sometimes things are just simple like that. Thanks for answer :)