# symfony 2.8 override CRUD skeleton template

Tags: symfony, templates, overriding, crud

According to https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/index.html I did copy and modify the templates like this :

```
/var/www/mdm/app/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle$ tree
.
└── skeleton
    └── crud
        ├── actions
        │   ├── delete.php.twig
        │   ├── edit.php.twig
        │   ├── index.php.twig
        │   ├── new.php.twig
        │   └── show.php.twig
        ├── controller.php.twig
        └── views
            ├── index.html.twig.twig
            ├── others
            │   └── record_actions.html.twig.twig
            └── show.html.twig.twig
```

and now, when I `doctrine:generate:crud --entity....`  the views are located under the /app/Resources/views/  and not under  `/src/../.../Resources/views/...`

I would prefer to have the views under `/src/Me/MyBundle .`

I have  the generator declared like this

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'), true)) {
...
$bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
```

and my bundle is under the Prod environment.

What's wrong when I copy the files under `/app/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle`? Why do the generated files are going under `/app`?

Comment: Find out why ... nothing to do with the generator .... :( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314076/new-option-asked-about-multiple-application-when-generating-a-bundle-since-symfo

Answer (score 0):

It's a new feature , not a bug or my poor knowledge or poor coding ...
[New option asked about Multiple Application when generating a bundle since Symfony 2.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34314076/new-option-asked-about-multiple-application-when-generating-a-bundle-since-symfo)